# How to store indivudual bits from a variable?

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

For example:

I got an input = `0x5A ( 0101 1010 )`.

I want to store the first 4 bits or the last 4 bit.

Comment: Using bitwise operators.

Answer (score 6):

```
unsigned char lower = input & 0xF;
unsigned char upper = (input >> 4) & 0xF;
```

Note that the last `& 0xF` is there in case your data type contains more bits than 8.

Comment: Note:  the type `char` can be either `signed`, `unsigned` or `compiler dependent`.  A better definition is to use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, so you can access all the bits.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks. Changed to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

just use the & operator to apply a mask:

```
input = 0x5a & 0xf0;
```

this would yield 0b01010000. Depending on what you want you could shift the selected bits to the right like

```
input = (0x5a & 0xf0)>>4;
```

So to get to the lower half you would use

```
input = 0x5a & 0x0f;
```